# Redirect user to my own website for completing the payment, (from shopify checkout)

Tags: shopify, payment-gateway, shopify-app, shopify-api, payment-processing

I am already having my store built in shopify. My aim is to get the customer make payment on custom website that I have built on my own, as the payment provider I want to use is not supported by shopify. Can someone please help me with the following queries:

1. How to redirect from checkout page to my own custom payment page with the order details?
2. I know how to use REST APIs only and not graphql, so will I still be able to accomplish the task?

I am stuck and not able to proceed. Could you please help me?

P.S. The payments provider that I am looking to use is converge. If you happen to know any workarounds that could solve my problem, please also let me know.